# How do I update my own Mercurial Fork with the lastest code in the main code base?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've got a fork of some Codeplex project. I wish to update my fork with the latest code in the official code (is that the trunk?).

How can I do this?

I'm also using [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.org/) on Win7 x64.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The commands are `pull` (to fetch the remote changes), and `update` to update your working directory to the most recent changeset.

Since you don't seem very familiar with the way Mercurial works, it would be a very good idea to read some introductory material like:

- http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/
- http://hginit.com/
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/quickstart
- http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html

Comment: My problem was that i needed to commit my current changes, before I could merge with any other changesets. I think i've got it now.